# Python index in nested for loop

Tags: python

I can put it in another example:

```
q=[[100,101,103,104],[201,202,204],[301,302,304],[401,402,403]]

for index, item in enumerate(q):
      for i,t in enumerate(q[index]):
          if q[index][i+1]-q[index][i]==2:
             print index, i, q[index][i]
```

which returns

```
0 1 101
```

it supposed to return

```
0 1 101
1 1 202
2 1 302
```

it seems the break statement  break the loop so it stops at the first list.

if I modify it by

```
 for index, item in enumerate(q):
        try:
            for i range(len(q[index]-1)):
                if q[index][i+1]-q[index][i]==2:
                    print index, i, q[index][i]
        except IndexError:
                break
```

Of course it is good, but I still want to know if there is a way that not to have to reduce the index as the last item is valuable as well.

Comment: Do you want to print the contents in the p list like a,b,c, etc ?

Comment: The original index is still available, it's just being printed multiple times because you're doing so inside a loop. The items in `p` are also easily available, they are literally called `item`. What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through list of list you may use this code:

```
p=[['a','b','c','d'],
   ['a','c','e','d'],
   ['a','b','z','x']]

for i,item in enumerate(p):
    for j,x in enumerate(item):
        print i,j,x
```

Output:

```
0 0 a
0 1 b
0 2 c
0 3 d
1 0 a
1 1 c
1 2 e
1 3 d
2 0 a
2 1 b
2 2 z
2 3 x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for index,item in enumerate(p):
     print 'top', index     #The index is at this level
     for x in range(len(item)):
         print 'loop' ,index  # Not this level where you print it.
```